# Convert Style ts file from Material V4 to V5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to migrate from material v4 to v5, the issue i am facing is previously I had a styles.ts file that I would import into my component and the start of the class looked like this:

```
import {
  defaultFont,
  primaryColor,
  infoColor,
  successColor,
  warningColor,
  dangerColor,
  grayColor,
} from "../material-kit-pro-react";
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

export const typographyStyle = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  defaultFontStyle: {
```

I then updated the imports to the following:

```
import {
  defaultFont,
  primaryColor,
  infoColor,
  successColor,
  warningColor,
  dangerColor,
  grayColor,
} from "../material-kit-pro-react";
import { makeStyles, Theme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { createStyles } from '@mui/styles';

export const typographyStyle = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => createStyles({
```

This uses the @mui imports, but in my actual class I get the following error:

```
const typographyStyle: never
import typographyStyle
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'never' has no call signatures.
```

My component is pretty basic and it looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { typographyStyle } from "assets/jss/material/typography/typographyStyle";
export interface TypographyProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}
export function Danger(props: TypographyProps) {
  const classes = typographyStyle();
  const { children } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.defaultFontStyle + " " + classes.dangerText}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error comes from `const classes = typographyStyle();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That´s occuring because `makeStyles` import has been moved to `@mui/styles`, so your import must be:

```js
import { Theme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
```

Also, according to `MUI` documentation:

> @mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the @mui/material anymore, deprecated in v5. If you don't want to have both emotion & JSS in your bundle, please refer to the @mui/system documentation which is the recommended alternative.

And

> We have replaced JSS with emotion as a default styling solution while adding support for styled-components at the same time. We recommend migration your customization from JSS/makeStyles/withStyles to the new APIs: styled and the sx prop

So, with `MUI` v5 you should probably go with `sx` or `styled` instead `makestyles`. You can take a better look [here](https://mui.com/blog/mui-core-v5/#change-of-the-styling-solution) and [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/).