# Material UI makeStyles does not work when I try to import it

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Good day, I am trying out Material UI and right now I am facing issues where I try to create "useStyles" using the makeStyles module. Here is the code:
[App.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpE3X.png)

Here is the [package.json file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfbVB.png)

I don't know whether I am doing something wrong or if I haven't imported something correct, can y'all help me out?

Comment: Take a look into this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72472413/convert-style-ts-file-from-material-v4-to-v5/72476554#72476554). Your error its related to a wrong import.

Comment: I tried the solution by changing the import from "@mui/material" to "@mui/styles", but it generates an error: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve @mui/styles in C:\dev\my-island\src"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

makeStyles is not longer exported from @mui/material/styles. It is now export from @mui/styles.

Here:

Install: `npm install @mui/styles`

Then Import:

`import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';`

Comment: This solution worked, thank you! I also found out that "makeStyles" is deprecated as of MUIv5 and that it is not compatible with React.StrictMode and React 18, from here out on I will probably use the MUI sx props to do my stylings.