# "Type 'never' has no call signatures" using withStyles in a React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

My problem is the error "This expression is not callable. Type 'never' has no call signatures."

Seen in the following code

```
import React from 'react'
import {Component} from "react";
import {Grid, withStyles} from "@mui/material";

const styles = (theme: any) => ({
    root: {
        background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
        border: 0,
        borderRadius: 3,
        boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px',
    },
});

class AnswerButton extends Component<AnswerButtonProps>{
    constructor(props: any){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <Grid >
                wew
            </Grid>
        )
    }

}

interface AnswerButtonProps {
    classes: any,
}

export default withStyles(styles)(AnswerButton);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error here
```

Is using React.Component inadvisable these days? Every solution I find online suggests making AnswerButton a normal `const` variable and using `useEffect` instead to monitor changes.

Comment: Take a look into this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72472413/convert-style-ts-file-from-material-v4-to-v5/72476554#72476554). Your error its related to a wrong import. You also need to install `@mui/styles` to this take effect.

Comment: See [this](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api) example.